# Indexing for Foreign Keys in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, foreign-keys

I am using SQL Server.

Is it needed to use index for any foreign key for improving speed?

Or will SQL Server do it automatically when I define foreign keys?

Comment: Index tuning is an art.  And you don't want too many or too little.  Here is a helper, maybe : https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server will not automatically add an index when creating a foreign key.
An index on that foreign key may help improve performance. But usually there are more columns needed from that table, so it might be a better decision to add a few more columns needed (either being part of the index or as included columns).

Comment: More specific note: Indexing foreign key columns mainly speeds up DELETE operations, as it can quickly tell if the row can be deleted without having to scan other tables.

Comment: @pmbAustin: and having an index on the foreign key column **also** helps with `JOIN` operations, since the FK data can be read in sorted order!